# Stevens' TCP/IP Illustrated graphics

Tags: architecture, network-programming, tcp

I am doing research on flow charts and other graphics and diagrams.

Stevens in TCP / IP Illustrated, when explaining a protocol or flow, use a chart with two vertical lines, "client" and "server" and arrows between them. Anyone know the name of the diagrams in the book?

Anybody knows other types of diagrams or can list them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not familiar with the book, but it sounds like you're describing a UML [Sequence Diagram](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/sequenceDiagram.htm):

[image]

If you'd like to make your own, [WebSequenceDiagrams](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/) is a great free online resource.

UML has a [number of other diagrams](http://www.agilemodeling.com/essays/umlDiagrams.htm) for representing code which you may find helpful.

Comment: If I recall correctly the diagrams in Stevens also support describing messages not arriving in order (by way of diagonal lines that cross each other), which you can't do with traditional sequence diagrams AFAIK.